# Can not see my class using classnames and React?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, class-names

Using React and classnames to do styles. I get no errors but I get undefined when I console.log(styles.uiPad). I do get an object when I console.log(styles). My classnames import component also gets console.logged successfully but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? Is this a webpack thing?

Here are my imports:

```
import styles from '../assets/stylesheets/base.scss'
import classNames  from 'classnames'
```

This is my render:

```
<div className={classNames(styles.uiPad)}></div>
```

Comment: what is the output of `styles.uiPad`?

Comment: @chazsolo undefined

Answer (score 1):

You are importing a Sass file. You need to compile Sass into CSS before importing it.

Comment: It is compiling through webpack